# Compactness of a set of matrix polynomials with a norm restriction

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials

Suppose

- $P_\Delta (\lambda) = (A_m + \Delta _m)\lambda^m + \cdots + (A_1 + \Delta_1)\lambda^1 + (A_0 + \Delta_0)$  is a matrix polynomial,  and $\lambda $ is a complex variable.
- $A_j,\Delta_j \in {C^{n \times n}},(j = 0,1,2,\ldots,m)$
- $\left\| \Delta _j \right\| < \varepsilon ,(j = 0,1,2,\ldots,m)$ where $\left\| \cdot \right\|$ is any subordinate matrix norm (i.e., a norm [induced](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Induced_norm) by a vector norm.)
- $A = \left\{ P_\Delta (\lambda ):\left\| \Delta_j \right\| < \varepsilon, j = 0,1,2,\ldots,m \right\}$ , and $A_j$  in $A$ is fix

Is this true that $A$ is compact?

Comment: Are the $A_j$ fixed in the definition of $P_{\Delta}$, or can they vary freely in the definition of $A$?

Comment: Is the norm in question is the spectral norm?

Answer (score 2):

$A$ is not compact since it is not closed.  However, the closure of $A$, which is given by
$$
\overline A = \left\{ P_\Delta (\lambda ):\left\| \Delta_j \right\| \leq \varepsilon, j = 0,1,2,\ldots,m \right\}
$$
Is compact.  In order to show that this is the case, it suffices (by Heine-Borel) to show that it is bounded.

A valid norm on the space of polynomials is 
$$
\left\|\sum_{j} M_j \lambda^j \right\| = \max_{j} \|M\|
$$
Now, for any $P_\Delta \in \overline A$, we have
$$
\|P_\Delta\| = \max_j \|A_j + \Delta_j\| \leq
\max_{j} (\|A_j\| + \|\Delta_j\|) \leq 
\left(\max_j \|A_j\|\right) + \epsilon
$$